# SQL Server : how to use a variable with multiple variables in a case statement in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to build a simple lookup table that will have its own web page display. I am providing simple search variables, and one of those variables is Status. I am looking for them to be able to Choose from Active, Inactive, or both, I am looking to easily look for both at once.  There are other status in the database such as 'D' for a soft delete that I do not want returned at all.

```
Declare @stat nvarchar(5) = 3

Select [Status] 
from tableUser
where [Status] in (CASE @stat
                      WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
                      WHEN 2 THEN 'I'
                      WHEN 3 THEN 'A','I'
                   END)
```

The above is what I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `CASE` statement to produce an *expression*, but that's not how it works. `CASE` statements produce *values* (which can be included as expressions, but the expressions must still reduce to values at query compile time). `'A','I'` does not reduce to a value, so you cannot use it as the result of a `CASE` statement.

Instead, write the condition more like this:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE WHEN @stat = 1 AND [Status] = 'A' THEN 1
               WHEN @stat = 2 AND [Status] = 'I' THEN 1
               WHEN @stat = 3 AND [Status] IN ('A', 'I') THEN 1
               ELSE 0 END
```

or remove the `CASE` expressions and build all that directly into the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (    (@stat = 1 AND [Status] = 'A') 
        OR (@stat = 2 AND [Status] = 'I')
        OR (@stat = 3 AND [Status] IN ('A', 'I')) 
      )
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly, I was completely overthinking what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Just use boolean logic:

```
WHERE (@stat IN (1, 3) AND Status = 'A') OR
      (@stat IN (2, 3) AND Status = 'I')
```

Comment: Logically this probably should work, but trying this resulted in a good deal of time to pull data.

Comment: @EricPruitt . . . I'm not sure what that means.  This should really have about the same performance as most other solutions in SQL Server.  In some databases -- and perhaps in a future incarnation of SQL Server -- this would be able to use an index (using what is called a "skip scan") whereas the `case` version would not.